# XOR Gate implemented with BC547 transistors not working

Tags: digital-logic, ttl

I have checked and rechecked the wiring on my breadboard against the circuit shown in the schematic a dozen times and can't for the life of me understand why it is not working. Can anyone see a fault in the schematic? The circuit implements an XOR gate, with a red LED as output.

The behaviour I get out of the breadboard circuit is as follows: Q3 is on with both switches open, as it should be. SW1 causes Q2 to turn on and SW2 causes Q1 to turn on. I have checked the wiring to the bases of Q1 and Q2 and they both connect to the correct switches. Q4 and Q5 will not turn on when their respective switches are closed.

[image]

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0k39.png  Q2 and Q4 must not share their base inputs at different emitter voltage levels

Comment: Q1and Q2 (at least) need base pulldown resistors (so there is a valid DC level at the base with the switches open).

Comment: So, both pretty similar problems to your previous question, Mario. Might want to look up the three classical BJT circuits

Comment: Will do Marcus. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @Peter Smith I added pull-down resistors to the bases off Q1 and Q2, but the circuit is still not working. Oddly, I measured 1.2 volts across the collector emitter of Q2 with the resistors added and the switch open.

Comment: Q2 messes with Q4's base voltage and so on. Feed each base via its own resistor from SW2; same for SW1.